# Storing session variables in MVC between servlet and JSPs (error status 500)

Tags: java, eclipse, model-view-controller, session-variables

When I run my dynamic web page, I get an error "java.lang.NumberFormatException: null" in my console after seeing that I get a status 500 page.

The code is supposed to ask the user to guess a number between 0-1000. If the user guesses incorrectly, it allows the user to guess again using the same session variables (target number and number of guesses are stored). This continues until the user guesses correctly of what the target number is. I am also avoiding using the hidden text option to store the variables.

I've already looked up what the error message means but I couldn't figure out where is it applying to as the status error is very vague.

Any help is appreciated...

**Error message from console:**

```
Oct 20, 2018 11:59:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [controllers.GameServlet] in context with path [/GuessingGame_MVC_Version] threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at controllers.GameServlet.doPost(GameServlet.java:47)
    at controllers.GameServlet.doGet(GameServlet.java:38)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**index.jsp (first page) :**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>

<%@ page import="model.GameNumber" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Guessing Game - MVC Version</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Guessing Game - MVC Version</h1>

  <p>
     Welcome to our guessing game!
  </p>

  <p>
     Please guess a number between 0 and 1000.
  </p>

  <form name="guessForm" action="doGuess" method="get">
     <label>
        Guess 1: 
     </label>
     <input type="text" name="guess" /><br />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Make Guess">

  </form>


</body>
</html>
```

**GameServlet.java (servlet):**

```
package controllers;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.util.*;

import model.GameNumber;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class GameServlet
 */
@WebServlet(
        description = "A servlet to control our simple guessing game", 
        urlPatterns = { 
                "/GameServlet", 
                "/doGuess"
        }, 
        initParams = { 
                @WebInitParam(name = "Guesses", value = "1"), 
                @WebInitParam(name = "Minimum", value = "0"),
                @WebInitParam(name = "Maximum", value = "1000")
        })
public class GameServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Random rand = new Random();
    int target = rand.nextInt(1000);

    int guesses=1;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public GameServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.doPost(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        // get input - guess
        GameNumber guess = new GameNumber(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("guess")));

        // initialize output
        String msg = "";
        String url = "/guess.jsp";

        // compare the guess with the target
       if( guess.getValue() == target ){
           // winner
           msg = "Correct! You got it in " + guesses + " guesses.";
           url = "/correct.jsp";
       } else {
           // next guess
           guesses++;
           if ( guess.getValue() < target ) {
               //low
               msg = "Incorrect guess! Guess higher next time.";
           } else {
               // high
               msg = "Incorrect guess! Guess lower next time.";
           }
       }
       //store guesses and target as session attributes
       HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("target", target);
        session.setAttribute("guesses", guesses);

       // add values to request object to pass to the destination
       request.setAttribute("msg", msg);


       // send control to the next component
       RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
       dispatcher.forward(request, response);

       RequestDispatcher dispatcherr = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
       dispatcherr.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

**guess.jsp :**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>

<%@ page import="model.GameNumber" %>

<%
  // get the inputs from the request and session attributes

  String msg = (String) request.getAttribute("msg");

  Integer targett = (Integer) session.getAttribute("target");
  int target = targett.intValue();

  Integer guessess = (Integer) session.getAttribute("guesses");
  int guesses = guessess.intValue();
  // output the form to the client
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Guessing Game - MVC Version</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Guessing Game - MVC Version</h1>

  <p>
     <%= msg %>
  </p>

  <form name="guessForm" action="doGuess" method="get">
     <label>
        Guess <%= guesses %>: 
     </label>
     <input type="text" name="guess" /><br />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Make Guess">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**correct.jsp :**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%
  String msg = (String) request.getAttribute("msg");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Guessing Game - MVC Version</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1>Guessing Game - MVC Version</h1>

<%= msg %>

<p>
<a href=index.jsp>
  Play Again
</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**GameNumber (model):**

```
package model;

import java.util.Random;

public class GameNumber {

    private int value;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public GameNumber() {
        value = 0;
    }

    /**
     * @param value
     */
    public GameNumber(int value) {
        if (value < 0) {
            this.value = 0;
        } else {
           this.value = value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the value
     */
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * @param value the value to set
     */
    public void setValue(int value) {
        if (value < 0) {
            this.value = 0;
        } else {
           this.value = value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * A simple method that sets value to a random integer between minimum and maximum
     * @param minimum the minimum value in the range
     * @param maximum the maximum value in the range
     */
    public void setRandom(int minimum, int maximum){
        Random random = new Random();
        this.value = random.nextInt(maximum - minimum) + minimum;
    }

    /**
     * a simple method to adjust the value up 1 unit
     */
    public void increment(){
        this.value++;
    }


}
```

**Try catch at guess (Gives same error) :**

```
GameNumber guess = null;
        try {
        guess = new GameNumber(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("guess")));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Number format Excdption!");
        }
```

Comment: What value are you assigning to `guess`? If your're **not** passing an int you will get a `NumberFormatException`

Comment: I am calling  GameNumber guess = new GameNumber(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("guess"))); in the servlet. It is declared as a form in the index.jsp. @NicholasK

Comment: Yes I can see that. What I'm trying to say is that your code would work fine if you just pass an `int`. Maybe you didn't and hence you are getting a `NumberFormatException`

Comment: I think I am understanding you incorrectly... Could you please verify for me? 

I thought parameters are always sent as a String variable so I need to parse it to be an int? Please correct me if I am wrong. @NicholasK

Comment: Yes that's right. But if the String you pass is not a number (a number within the range of an int), you cant parse it to an Integer. That's when you get a `numberformatexception`

Answer (score 1):

When I deployed your application with the mentioned jsp and servlet 
It will work fine but I have noticed that there are some error in tomcat console at your GameServlet 
since you are forwarding the request twice which is already been done

**i.e. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed**

Hence in your GameServlet java, under doPost

comment the last line (mentioned below)

```
  RequestDispatcher dispatcherr = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
   dispatcherr.forward(request, response);
```

and add

```
return; // not a must but helps in certain situations
```

**about the error message you have mentioned
It will only occur if you pass a string message in the Text box.**
Additional check can be applied for the same at runtime.

Comment: @Rugh does it helps you ?

Comment: I have tried your recommendations but it gives me the same error. java.lang.NumberFormatException: null. @Hades

Comment: what is the value that you are trying on ??

Comment: Quite confused why it would work for you but not me... Would it be too much to ask for an export of what you have?

Comment: nope I will share the code with you ... meanwhile what are the values that you are trying ??

Comment: I am putting in int values... 500, 700, 300, etc.

Comment: May I ask what the inputs were that you were using? @Hades

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine and as per your comments it seems you aren't passing the right values to your servlet.

You are right when you say the values are passed as Strings to the servlet. Let's try an understand what a NumberFormatException is. From the docs :

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a
>   string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have
>   the appropriate format.

The below code will work as the String "10" can be converted to an int.

```
    String str = "10";
    int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

But this would cause a `NumberFormatException`

```
    String str = "hi";
    int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

In your case you are passing a *String* which can't be converted to an *int*, hence it is failing.

Comment: I have been using int numbers like 500, 3, 5, 80 in the input though... I have never put inputs in a String. Am I wrong to put in int variables like 500? @NicholasK

Comment: Are there any spaces in your input? A leading or trailing space can also cause it to fail.

Comment: Nope, no spaces. Only the numerical values in the input... Do you think it could have to do with something besides the input variable? @NicholasK

Comment: No. That is the only place you are trying to format. To confirm wrap this line `GameNumber guess = new GameNumber(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("guess")));` in a `try-catch` block, debug it and see if it fails there.

Comment: >GameNumber guess = null;
     try {
        guess = new GameNumber(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("guess")));
     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("Number format Excdption!");
     }

It does not fail there

Comment: Hmm. Is it failing somewhere else then? Do you have the stacktrace?

Comment: Also, on closer inspection of your stack-trace posted in the question - it seems that `null` is being passed to your servlet on some occassions.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I ended up figuring out why it wasn't working. My server wasn't running properly and so I tried running it on another computer that I have and worked fine.